# Send html form data to database through php without switching page

Tags: php, jquery, html, mysql, forms

Hey guys so i have a form:

```
<form action="signup.php" method="post" class="cd-form">
                <p class="fieldset">
                  <input class="full-width has-padding has-border" type="text" required maxlength="15" placeholder="First Name" name="primeiro_nome" />         
              </p>
                <p class="fieldset">
                  <input class="full-width has-padding has-border"  type="text" required  maxlength="15" placeholder="Last Name" name="segundo_nome">
                </p>
                <p class="fieldset">
                  <input class="full-width has-padding has-border"  type="email" required maxlength="50"  placeholder="E-mail" name="o_email">
                </p>
                <p class="fieldset">
                    <input class="full-width" type="submit" value="Sign Up!">
                </p>        
            </form>
```

And you may notice that the action is calling "signup.php" :

```
    <?php
 $con=new mysqli ("localhost","root","","chroniclemark");
    mysqli_set_charset($con, 'utf8mb4');
    if($con->connect_error)
    {
        echo $con->connect_errno;
        die("Database Connection Failed");
    }
    if(($_POST['primeiro_nome']) != ""){

    $sql = "INSERT INTO users (nome, sobrenome, email) 
             VALUES('{$con->real_escape_string($_POST['primeiro_nome'])}', '{$con->real_escape_string($_POST['segundo_nome'])}', '{$con->real_escape_string($_POST['o_email'])}')";
        $insert = $con->query($sql);

}
?>
```

And this is working. The data from the form is getting inserted into my database. The problem i have is that the main page closes when the form is submitted and the "signup.php" page opens instead of it.

How do i fix this? I would very much like to have a "Thank you for signing up" popping up on the same page instead of it switching to another one.

Comment: Where you want user to redirect after insertion? Like after signup page you want to still on this page. Where you want to show the message?

Comment: @Programmer Blog same page

Comment: you have a choice between using your entire code in one file and using "self" for the action or use ajax. Edit: since you tagged as jquery, then use ajax

Comment: @Fred -ii- I'll use ajax, then but i have no idea how

Comment: @MarkCoelho please refer to the answer below about ajax. let me know if you face an issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use AJAX to save data to database and show user a message in same page. Clicking on button a request is sent to server, data is saved into database, on success or failure a response is returned then show a message to user.

**Form**

First Give ids to input types in you form and add a message div.

```
<form  method="post" class="cd-form">
            <p class="fieldset">
              <input class="full-width has-padding has-border" type="text" required maxlength="15" placeholder="First Name" id="primeiro_nome" />         
          </p>
            <p class="fieldset">
              <input class="full-width has-padding has-border"  type="text" required  maxlength="15" placeholder="Last Name" id="segundo_nome">
            </p>
            <p class="fieldset">
              <input class="full-width has-padding has-border"  type="email" required maxlength="50"  placeholder="E-mail" id="o_email">
            </p>
            <p class="fieldset">
                <input class="full-width" id='saverecords' type="button" value="Sign Up!">
            </p>
```

**jQuery Code to send AJAX request to server**

Add a script tag include jQuery and inside click event get values of fields and then post to php page:

```
<script src=”http://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js”></script>

<script type=”text/javascript”> 

$(function(){ 

    $("#saverecords").on('click', function(){ 

        var pnome  = $("#primeiro_nome").val();

        var sname  = $("#segundo_nome").val();

        var email  = $("#o_email").val();

        $.ajax({ 

          method: "POST",
          url: "saverecords.php",

          data: {"pname": pname, "sname": sname, "email": email},

         }).done(function( data ) { 
            var result = $.parseJSON(data); 

            var str = '';

            if(result == 1) {

              str = 'Signup successfull.';

            }else{
              str = 'Data could not be saved. Please try again'; 
            }

          $("#message").html(str);

      });

   }); 

</script>
```

**php server side code:**

Please change it according to your requirement

Create a php page:  saverecords.php
 In saverecords.php you can insert data into database.

```
$conn = new mysqli($host, $username, $password, $dbname);
$pname  = $_POST['pname'];

$sname  = $_POST['sname'];

$email  = $_POST['email'];
$sql    = "insert into tablename (pname, sname, email) values (?, ?, ?)  ";

$stmt   = $conn->prepare($sql);

$stmt->bind_param('sss', $pname, $sname, $email);

  if($stmt->execute()){

     $result = 1;

  }

}

echo $result;

$conn->close();
```

If you still face issue please visit this link you can find a detailed tutorial on how to use [jQuery Ajax](http://programmerblog.net/jquery-ajax-get-example-php-mysql/) with php mysqli

Comment: There are a few mistakes like pnome  instead of pname in the jQuery. But it works with some alterations.*edit* I will look to improve the code.

Comment: @MarkCoelho yes you can update according to your requirement. I just gave as example, Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You have to use [AJAX](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/AJAX/Getting_Started) instead of directly submitting the form
You send POST request with JS [XMLHttpRequest](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest) or [Fetch_API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API) to `signup.php`, get the response and show the "Thank you for signing up" popup

Comment: So my php stays the same, then i make the form call the javascript?

Comment: Yep, your PHP code stays the same. From html script tag or external script file you make an AJAX request

Answer (score 1):

There are mainly two ways you can do this.
1. You can use Jquery $.ajax method to send data, get a response and display your message.
2. Or you can simply let the php page it self do the processing. Add a submit button.

Change your `<form action="signup.php" method="post" class="cd-form">`to

```
<form action="" method="post" class="cd-form">
```

Add below after the form.

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST["submit"]){
  //do your processing here
  //at the end of processing you can use echo or HTML to display a thank you message
}
?>
```

Comment: I see, i wil ltry this but i tagged the question jQuery so i'd like the AJAX method

Comment: Try this link. https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_ajax_get_post.asp. Once you get a success response then proceed to show the thank you message

Answer (score 0):

You can make action page run inside an iframe so your form page remains on top

just like that:

```
<form action="signup.php" method="post" class="cd-form" target="my_iframe">
            <p class="fieldset">
              <input class="full-width has-padding has-border" type="text" required maxlength="15" placeholder="First Name" name="primeiro_nome" />         
          </p>
            <p class="fieldset">
              <input class="full-width has-padding has-border"  type="text" required  maxlength="15" placeholder="Last Name" name="segundo_nome">
            </p>
            <p class="fieldset">
              <input class="full-width has-padding has-border"  type="email" required maxlength="50"  placeholder="E-mail" name="o_email">
            </p>
            <p class="fieldset">
                <input class="full-width" type="submit" value="Sign Up!">
            </p>        
        </form>


        <iframe id="my_iframe" name="my_iframe" style="display:none"></iframe>
```

Also you can send form data to your PHP page by using jquery:

```
$(document).on('submit','.cd-form',function(e){
e.preventDefault();
$.ajax( {
url: "signup.php",
type: 'POST',
data: new FormData( this ),
cache: false,
dataType: "json",
success: function(r){
alert("data sent successfully");
}
} );
} );
```